# Merge partitions (that aren't next to each other)?

Tags: fdisk

All,

So I've already read through quite a few threads, but didn't quite find an identical situation. I have 4 partitions, and I want two. I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS. I have gParted installed (KDE wm) and tried to re-size the partitions, but it just moves them around, rather than merge them. (They're not next to each other) Is this something I'll be forced to use fdisk for? Have a photo, but can't post because I'mma n00b, I guess.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00006727

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          62      497983+  83  Linux
/dev/sda2              63        2432    19030016   8e  Linux LVM
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda3            2433       13054    85321215   83  Linux

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/turnkey-root
                       17G  2.0G   14G  13% /
none                 1004M  188K 1004M   1% /dev
none                 1007M     0 1007M   0% /dev/shm
none                 1007M   84K 1007M   1% /var/run
none                 1007M     0 1007M   0% /var/lock
none                 1007M     0 1007M   0% /lib/init/rw
```

Thanks,

Joel

[image]

Comment: Can you upload the photo somewhere and I can post it for you.

Comment: http://i1077.photobucket.com/albums/w464/Jcb1974/gparted.png

Answer (score 0):

You can't merge partitions.  You have to back up the files from one of them, delete it, then expand the other into the new free space, then restore the files.  If the free space is not next to the partition you want to extend, you will have to move the partitions around.

Update: If you have Windows and don't mind spending money on proprietary software, [This Product](http://www.acronis.eu/promo/ADDH/disk-director-11-home.html?source=eu_googleADD_b&ad=add&c=7594565694&k=acronis%20disk%20director&gclid=CPGT67OMl7ACFcshtAodZ0Cd1g) claims to be able to merge partitions directly.

Comment: Yes you can merge partitions.  Take a look at Acronis Disk Director. http://www.acronis.eu/promo/ADDH/disk-director-11-home.html?source=eu_googleADD_b&ad=add&c=7594565694&k=acronis%20disk%20director&gclid=CPGT67OMl7ACFcshtAodZ0Cd1g

Comment: @Mitch, it is proprietary, and for Windows, but good point.

Comment: You can create a boot CD that boots Linux, and it can be done.  I have done many times :)

Comment: Well, I'm a little averse to getting into fdisk, but no time like the present i suppose. (Sigh)

Comment: @JoelBailey, `fdisk` can only create and delete partitions.  You will want to use `gparted` to move and extend them.

Comment: Got it. Well, I've give it another go round then!

Comment: Just Download the trial version, create the boot CD and you`re done.

Comment: @JoelBailey, ahhh, `gparted` doesn't understand LVM, so to expand the LVM partition into the free space, you will need to use `fdisk`.  Put it in sector mode with the `u` command, delete the partition, and recreate it with the exact same start sector, and longer length.  It is vital that you recreate it with the same start sector.  Then you can use `pvresize` for LVM to recognize the extra space, and either create new logical volumes with `lvcreate` or extend existing ones with `lvresize`.