# How can I succesfully merge the two partitions shown using GParted?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, live-environment

[This is my current partition map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuPdD.png):

[image]

I am currently running GParted in an Ubuntu 12.04 live environment. I am having trouble finding out how to merge my unallocated space with `/dev/sda2`. I have heard that the partitions must be adjacent to each other to be able to merge, and if so I am 99% sure that if I reinstall my Ubuntu partition (`/dev/sda3`) to start at the end of the unallocated space rather than the beginning, I will be able to somehow MacGyver my way through this, although this is a last resort if even possible at all. I could use any help whatsoever.

Comment: Possible duplicate take a look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/141335/merge-partitions-that-arent-next-to-each-other#comment168968_141335

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)If you delete the extended partition that is there, sda3 in your case, and reinstall it at the end of the drive you will be able to extend the windows 7 partition to use the free space. You could also do this in the other order, delete the partition, extend windows, then re install ubuntu.

(2)You *might* be able to just move the partitions but that will depend on where you installed grub, on the partition or on the hard disk MBR. I would burn a bootloader such as chimera to a cd in case this dosent work 100%, it will probably allow you to boot into windows/ ubuntu anyway.

Comment: Thank you. To verify, in GParted to extend the drive it is as simple as dragging it?

Comment: Just click on the drive and click the resize option.

Comment: That seems simple enough.

Comment: If you are going to extent the windows drive i suggest doing it from windows disk manager and not gparted.

Comment: I definitely *would not* used windows disk manager; I used it once and it overwrote my entire logical group because none were NTFS and it doesn't 'understand' them. I lost an ubuntu installation and a separate drive for all my music. Only got half back.

Comment: Ok, then definitely use Gparted. Windows will ask you to chkdsk on boot though. Also, when partitioning, make sure to chose, "align to cylinder", which will avoid "partition is misaligned" errors in disk management. You will have to leave a couple of MB free between partitions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't merge a primary partition with an extended partition.  You can delete the extended partition, and then spend a lot of time making the primary partition bigger.  But then you'll just have a big primary NTFS partition, and you will probably have to spend even more time shrinking it to make room for Ubuntu.

If I were you, I would decide first how big you want your Windows partition.  If you want to continue using it, you probably want to make it bigger, since it's nearly full.  So, you will need to delete the extended partition.  Then you can make the Windows partition to whatever size you want it, and create an extended partition for Ubuntu and whatever other logical drives you want.  My advice is **do not create any more primary partitions** (ever).

If you wanted to switch to Ubuntu as your main system, you could leave things as they are, and install it in the existing extended partition.